# How can I control the brightness from the notification bar?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, htc-desire, screen-brightness, notification-bar

My friend has the `Galaxy S` and is able to control the brightness by sliding his finger over the notification-bar. He said he didn't install anything to have it (but he has a custom ROM, so that doesn't have to mean anything).

I have the `HTC Desire` running with the `Cyanogen` MOD. I tried finding a widget or something else that will allow me to control the brightness from the notification bar, but came up with nothing.

Can it be done?

Comment: I don't think widgets attach to the notification bar.

Comment: Yeah I would think you'd need a custom ROM/theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you have cyanogenmod, you can do it ;) 
Follow the below settings menus: 
Settings-> CyanogenMod Settings-> Interface -> Status bar tweaks -> 
Than make sure Status bar brightness control is checked.

Answer (score 4):

This is an undocumented feature in certain Samsung devices. Hold your finger over the notification bar and then sliding it left and right can increase/decrease brightness.

It started with the Galaxy S, IIRC. Also, "auto-brightness" setting must be turned off.

Comment: My Samsung Droid Charge also has this undocumented feature. What a great find! Thanks Sparx!